# AngularJS inject an HTML template and evaluate it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, smart-table

I'm fairly new to Angular JS and front-end in general but I have this requirement that I could not find an answer for.

I have a an array of column objects like so:

```
$scope.columns = [
    { header: 'Column 1', visible: true, template: '{{row.property1}}' },
    { header: 'Column 2', visible: true, template: '{{row.property2}}' },
    { header: 'Column 3', visible: true, template: '<a href="mailto:{{row.property3}}">{{row.property3}}</a>' },
    // ..
];

$scope.messages = [];
```

In HTML, I'm iterating over the rows and columns to produce a table (using Smart-table).

The problem is two fold, first of all I'm not aware of any way to have angular render the column template.  What I'm looking for is something like

```
<td ng-some-directive="col.template"></td>
```

A directive that takes an expression that evaluates to a string and then compiles and renders the string as an HTML template.  I've tried `ng-bind-html` and `ng-bind-template`.  `ng-bind-template` was promising but it expects a string, not an expression that evaluates to string.

```
<td ng-bind-template="{{col.template}}"></td>
```

Obviously doesn't work and simply renders the content of `col.template`

<s>The second issue is the scope of the template.  You can see I have used `row.property` which isn't reusable/desirable. I need the scope to take on the properties of the row so I can write my templates with only the knowledge of the type of object the template is designed for. eg</s>

```
 ... template: '{{property}}' },
```

Which is much cleaner.
[Solved with Angular plugin ngScope]

Thanks

Comment: Hi @rtlayzell, how did you solve it? If you did using a plugin which one then?